# Why my URI import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart'; is not working in vscode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

[image: import problem]

I cannot use my import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart'; although I installed it and restart my pc and run flutter pub get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First

`flutter clean`

And then

```
flutter pub get
```

This should solve your problem .